# How to combined String rows to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

| data A | data B |
| --- | --- |
| apple | apple, banana, cat |
| banana | apple, banana, cat |
| cat | apple, banana, cat |

```
SELECT 
  data A,
  '' as data B
From tbl_test;
```

If I have data like Column data A and I want to combined this data to another column like data b

How can I query this one and show like I want

Sorry for my news sql

Comment: Mention SQL server Version

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: Do not store data in csv format. It is bad database design.

Comment: jens thank for your recommend

Comment: `STRING_AGG` won't support in `SQL 2014` need to Use sub query `STUFF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `STUFF` we can combine all column data into single column by writing Subquery it will give's Result to all columns suitable for `SQL Server 2014`. Code is as follows.

```
select dataA,STUFF((
select ','+r.dataA
from TestTable as r
for xml path('')),1,1,'') as dataB From TestTable
```

Comment: Stuff just removes or adds characters, it doesn't combine anything, the combination is done by the for xml path "thing", your code is fine though

Comment: @siggemannen Thank you for your suggestion i'll modify answer accordingly